# Flutter: Autoroute : RouteGuard not working in AutoTabsScaffold

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-routes

I am trying add auth guard for my AutoTabsScaffold [bottom nav] but it's not working, It's working in other navigation pages but not just inside my landing page [where AutoTabsScaffold| Bottom Nav resides] am I missing something here?

using : `auto_route: ^3.2.4`  [[pub.dev]](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route)

class LandingPage

```
   return AutoTabsScaffold(

      backgroundColor: Theme
          .of(context)
          .scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        routes: const [
          HomeRouter(),
          CategoryRouter(),
          OrderRouter(),
          ProfileRoute(),
      ],
      bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {return}
```

class auth guard:

```
class RouteGuard extends AutoRedirectGuard {
  final AuthService authService;

  RouteGuard(this.authService) {
    authService.addListener(() {
      if (!authService.authenticated) {
        // should be called when the logic effecting this guard changes
        // e.g when the user is no longer authenticated
        reevaluate();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
    if (authService.authenticated) return resolver.next();
    router.push(
      LoginRoute(
        onLoginCallback: (_) {
          resolver.next();
          router.removeLast();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

router.dart

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page|Screen,Route',
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(page: OrderPreviewPage),
    AutoRoute(page: AddCardPage,),
    AutoRoute(page: PaymentPage,),
    AutoRoute(page: SplashPage, initial: true),
    AutoRoute(page: MyCartPage,),
    AutoRoute(page: IntroPage),
    AutoRoute(page: RegisterPage),
    AutoRoute(page: ProductDetailPage),
    AutoRoute(page: ProductListingPage),
    AutoRoute(page: CartSummaryPage,),
    AutoRoute(page: LoginPage, path: 'login'), //name: 'LoginRoute'
    AutoRoute(
      initial: true,
      page: LandingPage,

      path: 'landing',
      children: [
        AutoRoute(
          path: '',
          name: 'homeRouter',
          page: HomePage,
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: 'category',
          name: 'categoryRouter',
          page: CategoryPage,
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: 'orders',
          name: 'orderRouter',
          page: OrdersPage,
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: 'profile',
          guards: [RouteGuard],    //<------- here registered router guard but not working in Tabscaffold page
          page: ProfilePage,
        ),
        // RedirectRoute(path: '*', redirectTo: ''),

      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

Trying to add a route guard in the bottom navigation but it's not working as I expected. What am I missing here? [Github Issue](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/1041)

Comment: Hi is there an answer for this? I am also facing the same issue :)

Comment: If you want to add a `RouteGuard` you have to add it explicitly to every `AutoRoute` which should be checked.

Right now you only added it to the `ProfileRoute`. I think you might want to add it also to           `HomeRouter()`, `CategoryRouter()` and `OrderRouter()`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, guard isn't called with `AutoTabsScaffold`. After some investigation, it turns out that guards in `TabsRouter` are not [supported](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/1041#issuecomment-1112573098) .

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this, then? I am stuck in same problem.

Comment: I've tried to find, but failed. I decided not to use auto_route for now.

Comment: Oh I see, for me it was working with AutoRoute, when I switched the routes to AutoTabsRouter (wherever required) it stopped. As guards are not supported with TabsRouter but it's compatible with AutoRouter. If that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar structure and for me it work by adding guard at the top of nested navigation in your case in landing :

```
AutoRoute(
  initial: true,
  page: LandingPage,
  guards: [RouteGuard],   
  path: 'landing',
```