# Disable Caching AutoTabsRouter - Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, auto-route

I recently upgraded auto_route package and upgraded the tabs to AutoTabsRouter. But, my guarding stopped working. I checked here, it is not supported. [AutoTabsRouter - Guards are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72013662/flutter-autoroute-routeguard-not-working-in-autotabsscaffold)

Does anybody faced the same issue?

For now, I am moving my guarding to specific screen but, with TabsRouter, widgets are cached and it is not allowing me to re-build.

How actually can I disable caching for specific screen?

Thanks